# How to create modal type alert/ dialogbox in fbml or fbjs

Tags: facebook, modal-dialog, fbml, fbjs

I need to make a alert box or dialog box when popup it lock the back screen like a Modal type alert box. but this time i need in fbjs. or fbml any one can help me please...

Comment: fbml and fbjs is on the brink of deprecation. it is not advisable to use them now.

Answer (score 1):

One way to cheat this is to give the div a css attribute of `position: absolute` and align your div on top of your content, with a `z-index` of something higher than everything else on your page (typically, people use something like 100).  This becomes your modal container, and within it you'll just want to mimmic/copy the styles of a typical FB modal window.

Also, create another `div` at the top or bottom of your content, and give it css properties of `position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; opacity: .5; z-index: 50` (make sure z-index is less than your modal container).  This is your overlay, which blocks the content of the page from being interacted with until the user does something with your modal.

I would suggest going about the solution this way because like @dragonjet pointed out, FBML is deprecated, and you can't create new FBML applications anymore.  Without FBML there is no FBJS.